# Outputting custom field query from a plugin to the website header

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, custom-field, loop

I added the code below to the plugin that I'm working on to display the values of the custom fields but it shows up but blank.

```
function mySEO() {
    require('wp-site-gps-transport.php');
}

// Add hook for admin <head>
add_action('admin_head', 'mySEO');
// Add hook for front-end <head>
add_action('wp_head', 'mySEO');

add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'cmb_sample_metaboxes' );
```

When I add the content of the called file directly to the folder, it shows perfectly. However, I want the user of the plugin to only put value and not touch the code. Below is the code in the called file. Any ideas of what the problem could be?

```
<title><?php
if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {
    $title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title', true ); 
    if ( $title )
        echo $title . ' | ' . get_bloginfo('name');
    else
        wp_title('') . ' | ' . get_bloginfo('name');
}
?></title>

<?php
if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :  the_post();

    $description = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'description', true ); 
    printf( '<meta name="description" content="%s" />',
        ( $description ? $description : get_the_excerpt_rss() )
    );

    endwhile; endif;

} elseif ( is_home() ) {
    printf( '<meta name="description" content="%s" />',
        get_bloginfo('description')
    );
}

if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {

    if ( have_posts() ) :   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $keywords = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'keywords', true);
    printf ( '<meta name="keywords" content="%s" />',
          ( $keywords ? $keywords : the_excerpt_rss(); ?
    );

    endwhile; endif;

} elseif ( is_home() ) {
    printf( '<meta name="keywords" content="%s" />',
        get_bloginfo('keywords');
    );


}
```

Comment: This code is quite difficult to read, would be nice if you added line breaks and removed *unnecessary* opening and closing PHP tags... Also, use **bold** to highlight key words and **not all the text, as this is not smooth to read as well**.

Comment: @brasofilo I've submitted an edit that should clean up his code somewhat

Comment: @bungeshea, nice touch :), but still needs another reviewer to aprove the change. Dz slick, please check: [Why do people not split long lines when posting code here?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41289/185667) and also a good [IDE](http://netbeans.org/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aside from a few syntax errors in there with your `printf`s, the crux of the problem is things like this:

```
$title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title', true );
```

won't work in your included file because there is no `$post` in this scope, You have to globalize `$post` before you can use it:

```
global $post;
$title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title', true );
```